# Creating objects from IDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, .net, observablecollection, idatareader

I have created the following to create User objects with an ObservableCollection of UserModule objects called UserModules.

I have approx. 100000 user records, each user could have up to 10 module records and this is taking minutes to finish.

This may mean changing from IDataReader, open to suggestion. Can someone suggest a more efficient way to do this?

```
public void LoadUsers()
{
    clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("USERS");
    clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db_user_modules = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("USERS");
    try
    {
        db.setCommandText(@"SELECT * FROM Users");

        using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var user = new User();
                MapUser(reader, user);
                _users.Add(user);

                db_user_modules.setCommandText(@"SELECT MODULE_ID, USER_MODULE_ACCESS FROM USER_MODULE_SECURITY Where USER_ID = " + user.User_ID);

                using (var reader_user_modules = db_user_modules.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader_user_modules.Read())
                    {
                        MapUserModule(reader_user_modules, user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        db = null;
    }

}
```

MapUser

```
public static void MapUser(IDataRecord record, User user)
{
    try
    {
        user.User_ID = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(record, "USER_ID");
        user.Username = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "USERNAME");
        user.Name = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "NAME");
        user.Job_Title = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "JOB_TITLE");
        user.Department = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "DEPARTMENT");
        user.Company = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "COMPANY");
        user.Phone_Office = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "PHONE_OFFICE");
        user.Phone_Mobile = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "PHONE_MOBILE");
        user.Email = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "EMAIL");
        user.Password = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(record, "PASSWORD");
        user.Last_Login = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<DateTime>(record, "LAST_LOGIN");
        user.Status = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(record, "STATUS");
        user.Session_Timeout = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(record, "SESSION_TIMEOUT");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mapping User error: " + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

MapUserModule

```
private static void MapUserModule(IDataRecord record, User user)
{
    try
    {
        int m_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(record, "MODULE_ID");
        int uma = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(record, "USER_MODULE_ACCESS");

        user.UserModules.Add(new Users.UserModule(user.User_ID, m_id, uma));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Mapping UserModule error:\n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Search n+1 problem. The majority of your slowness should be because you tight loop on your `UserModule` query. Assuming you have 100000 users, that query is run 100000 times. Assuming a latency of 1ms (impossibly fast), to your database, that will take 100000 ms or 100s which equates to about 2 minutes. In short 2 minutes (at least) in your code is made up of network latency.

Comment: If I run it without adding the user modules then it takes about a second.

Comment: My advice, fetch all the UserModules in a single query, put them all into a `ILookup`. Then get all the Users and then do `user.UserModules = userModuleLookup[user.Id].ToList()`.

Comment: Sounds like an answer. I haven't used ILookup before I will do some research. If you enter this as an answer I would really appreciate an example on how to implement ILookup into my code.

Comment: I actually didn't read the code carefully enough--Aron's observation is *much* more likely the cause than the observable collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<UserModule> GetUserModules()
{
    using(var db = ....)
    db.setCommandText("SELECT * FROM USERMODULES");
    using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var userId = reader[...];
            var m_id = reader[...];
            var uma = reader[...];
            yield return new UserModule (userid, m_id, uma)
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    var userModulesLookup = GetUserModules().ToLookup(x => x.UserId);
    using (var db = ...)
    {
        db.setCommandText("SELECT * FROM USERS");
        using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var userId = reader["userId"];
                ...blah blah blah...
                var user = return new User();
                user.Modules = new ObservableCollection<UserModule>
                                     (userModulesLookup[userId]);
                ...blah blah blah...
                yield return user;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void LoadUsers()
{
    var users = GetUsers();
    foreach(var u in users)
        _users.Add(u);
}
```

Comment: This is great, however I have user.Modules defined as an ObservableCollection as well, is there any way to cast userModulesLookup into a Collection? At the moment it is throwing a Cannot implicitly convert type List to ObservableCollection.

Comment: Just use new ObservableCollection(userModulesLookup[userId])

Comment: Ok just as an update used ObservableCollection<UserModule>(userModulesLookup[userId]). Tested and it is now faster than before, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no faster solution than using a DataReader.

I would recommend you profile the code to see what is taking up most of the time.  IIRC, adding a large number of items to an observable collection one at a time is slow.  Try adding them to a List<> temporarily to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: That sounds realistic because of the fact that the ObservableCollection would observe every addition.  ObservableCollection has a constructor that takes a List so that could well be the way to go.  There's no AddRange method though, so that doesn't help for an existing collection and there's no method to temporarily suspend observation, which would have been nice.